# Difference between bootloader and Download mode in Samsung Galaxy tablets

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, boot, bootloader, odin

I'm working on Samsung Galaxy Tab tablets, specifically with Tab 3 (SM-T210) and Tab 4 (SM-T230), and being learning a bit about the boot and recovery images and the bootloader. I have not being able to find the answer to this very simple question: Is Download Mode Samsung's Bootloader? If not what is the difference?

Comment: Yes and no. The **Download Mode** is an interface between the Loke component, which resides in the bootloader, and Odin/Heimdall. In fact, if you issue the **reboot bootloader** from your device's command line, it will boot the Download Mode.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thanks for your comment. Do you have any tutorial or articles regarding the information you supplied, so I can read on?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have any direct link at hand. You may want to search at XDA. If you're interested in the Odin tool, though, I was researching its features, and you can find my notes under a question named **Odin configuration file analysis**, or something similar, in this very SE.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I issued the **reboot bootloader** and rebooted into normal mode, same happened when I issued the **adb reboot-bootloader**. The only one that worked was **adb reboot recovery**.

Comment: This is quite strange. It may be a difference noticed only on tablets? My S4 Mini does what I expected it to do. See if you can experiment on a Samsung smartphone, and if the result is the expected one.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman For realz though, is totally stealing your comment and reposting it as an answer like the guy did below allowed here on SE?

Comment: @AndyYan Nice objection. I'll downvote and flag the answer accordingly. Had he politely asked, I would've let him use my info, but it's not the case.

Comment: Downvote it if it's not an answer.  If it _is_, then don't post it as a comment.

Comment: @MatthewRead An answer is not such if it doesn't solve the issue, and that's why I usually post them as comments first. An answer which doesn't solve anything is pointless, thus I let any OP evaluate it before writing a real answer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes and no. The Download Mode is an interface between the Loke component, which resides in the bootloader, and Odin/Heimdall. In fact, if you issue the reboot bootloader from your device's command line, it will boot the Download Mode. (thanks to @death-mask-salesman)